# Date on H-Axis with log-scale (Google Chart)

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I need a log-scale on H-Axis formatted as DATE.

In the example you can see the H-Axis (0-100) visualized as log-scale, no problem. I need this scale to be actual Dates. I know if you got 2 dates or 2 timestamps you cant just *log* between them.

**Attempt**

x (H-Axis) are the `PAST_SECONDS` so provided 0-100 in case i want to look back 100 seconds.

**Problem**

As soon as i use a non Date-Time value im not able to Format the `PAST SECONDS` to a well formatted Date. Formatting would go like: `TIMESTAMP` + `PAST_SECONDS`

**Question**

Is there a way to get a formatting callback or else for the H-Axis labels?
If not, is there a way to get the formatted date (from `PAST_SECONDS`) into the popup?

Example with `PAST_SECONDS` as H-Axis(x)

```js
var chart_options = {
  hAxis: {
    logScale: true,
    direction: -1,
  },
  vAxes: {
    0: {
      title: 'A',
      viewWindowMode:'explicit',
      viewWindow: {
        max:100,
        min:1
      },
      gridlines: {style: "dashed",},
    },
    1: {
      title: 'B',
      viewWindowMode:'explicit',
      viewWindow: {
        max:100,
        min:1
      },
      gridlines: {color: 'transparent'},
    },
  },
  series: {
    0: {
      type: 'line',
      targetAxisIndex:0,
      color: '#C0504E',
    },
    1: {
      type: 'area',
      targetAxisIndex:1,
      color: '#4F81BC'
    }
  },
};

google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart'], 'language': 'en'});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
    chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart($('#chart').get(0));
    chart_data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    chart_data.addColumn('number', 'x');
    chart_data.addColumn('number', 'A');
    chart_data.addColumn('number', 'B');
    for( var i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
      chart_data.addRow([
        i,
        Math.round(Math.random()*10)+70,
        Math.round(Math.random()*20)+20
      ]);
    }
    chart.draw(chart_data, chart_options);  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: It will be best if you can do two things: 1. Use numbers (as you are) and provide the formatted representation for each value, using the object representation: {v: num, f: formattedNum} 2. Specify the 'ticks' option with the tick values you want to use, including the formatted representation of each in the same way as for data values.  This means you will have to figure out which tick values to show, which is not trivial if your data varies.

Comment: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50881138/5090771) for an example of formatting the tick labels...